# Is it logical to use generics here?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, refactoring

Originally the code is like this:

```
public interface IApplicableSystem
{
    string Name { get; }

    void Apply ( );
}

public class Effector
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EffectSystem : IApplicableSystem
{
    Effector Internal { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.Internal.Name; }
    }

    RelayCommand applyCommand;
    public ICommand ApplyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if ( applyCommand == null )
                applyCommand = new RelayCommand ( p => this.Apply ( ) );

            return applyCommand;
        }
    }

    public void Apply ( )
    {

    }

    public EffectSystem ( Effector value )
    {
        this.Internal = value;
    }
}
```

So there are many different types implementing `IApplicableSystem`, all where they differ is their `Name` property, `Apply` method and the type of the private `Internal` property that's used inside the class.

Should I use generic to make them like this?:

Is this reasonable? Mainly this reduces the amount of code in the other types implementing `IApplicableSystem`.

```
public abstract class GenericSystem<T> : IApplicableSystem
{
    protected T Internal { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return String.Empty; }
    }

    RelayCommand applyCommand;
    public ICommand ApplyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if ( applyCommand == null )
                applyCommand = new RelayCommand ( p => this.Apply ( ) );

            return applyCommand;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Apply ( )
    {

    }

    public GenericSystem ( T value )
    {
        this.Internal = value;
    }
}

public class EffectSystemGeneric : GenericSystem<Effector>
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return GetUniqueName ( base.Internal.Name ); }
    }

    public override void Apply ( )
    {
        Console.WriteLine ( "Do something" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is reasonable, but when overriding a virtual method, you have to use the override keyword, not virtual.  You may want to make the generic base class abstract instead, to force implementers to provide an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the generic makes sense, only because the type of the `Internal` property varies.  If it did not, a non-generic base class would work just as well.

If the `Name` property will always be `Internal.Name`, then you can declare the class:

```
public class GenericSystem<T> : IApplicableSystem where T : IName
```

Where `IName` is an interface which has a `Name` property, and `Effector` would implement that interface, and thus you can move the definition of the `Name` property into the base class instead of overriding it everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the definition of the Name property changes but this is beyond my control :O